# Connect to a VirtualBox guest through ssh

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, local

There are several VirtualBoxs running on a machine I have ssh'd into, part of `ps aux`:

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment workspace_1368637257 --startvm 61c3fb72-92e2-4505-a5bb-2becfc6a7278 --vrde config
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment workspace_1365093026 --startvm e10c4673-0c0b-4a29-b39f-f9d0d08f92c0 --vrde config
```

How do a connect to a particular one?  I've seen a lot about connecting remotely, NAT, RDP, I thought it would be as simple as using the argument for `--startvm` to specify which VM to connect to.  Could someone point me in the right direction for this please.  Thanks.

Comment: *How* do you want to connect to them? As in, what protocol? RDP? If so, do you want to utilize VBox RDP implementation on the host or do you want to connect to the RDP server in the client?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I'm a novice and ignorant so I didn't even think like this.  I've been flippantly `ssh`ing into servers and accessing them from the terminal provided without thinking about what is actually going on under the hood.  I had naïvely assumed I could do that same with a locally running VirtualBox.  Thanks for the prod in the right directly. I'll read up on RDP etc...  I actually don't think I care what protocol I use as long as from the same machine, I can access a terminal in the virtual machine.

Comment: The thing is, if your guest is running a Linux-based OS, there's a good chance SSHd is running on it. Then you'd only need the IP address of the guest to SSH into it. VBox also provides an RDP implementation where it will provide the virtual screen contents of the guests over RDP. In that case you would connect to the host on a specific port. If your guest is Windows, it could have an RDPd running in it, then you would connect to the guest again. All these methods are inherently different and will provide different levels of interaction with the system.